# How to iterate through a list of keywords to fill a function in Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, datareader, google-finance-api

I am doing a Finance project in Python. I am using pandas dataframes and DataReader to get stock data for different banks. I have a list of 'tickers' which are an input for the following function:

```
tickers= ['BAC','C','GS','JPM','MS','WFC']            # list of tickers
BAC = data.DataReader('BAC', 'stooq', start, end).    # example function for 1st element
```

I could write the function for each element of the list and store it in a different variable. But I would like to automate this process and instead create a function which iterates through the tickers and calls a variable to fill it in with whichever element in the list. Help me out?

Comment: "calls a variable to fill it in with whichever element in the list". What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is a simple for loop as a starting point:

```
returned_values = []
for tick in tickers:
    returned_values.append(data.DataReader(tick, 'stooq', start, end))
```

The returned_values list will contain all your returned values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setattr() to add a variable to a class, but you would need a class to hold the variables:

```
class DataReader:
    
    def __init__(self, ticker, something, start, stop):
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.something = something
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop

class test:
    
    def __init__(self, tickers):
        
        for t in tickers:
            setattr(self, t, DataReader(t, 'stooq', 1, 1))

new = test(['BAC','C','GS','JPM','MS','WFC'])
```

test:

```
print(new.BAC)
<__main__.DataReader object at 0x0000017847C10128>
```

However a better way would be holding the objects in a dictionary:

```
tickers = {t: DataReader(t, 'stooq', 1, 1) for t in ['BAC','C','GS','JPM','MS','WFC']}
```

output:

```
{'BAC': <__main__.DataReader at 0x17847d6af28>,
 'C': <__main__.DataReader at 0x17847d6ac18>,
 'GS': <__main__.DataReader at 0x17847d6af60>,
 'JPM': <__main__.DataReader at 0x17847d6afd0>,
 'MS': <__main__.DataReader at 0x17847d6a7f0>,
 'WFC': <__main__.DataReader at 0x17847d6a828>}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just store all the results in a `dict` and access whichever one you need:

```
my_dict = {t: data.DataReader(t, 'stooq', start, end) for t in tickers}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fill a dictionary like this:

```
tickers = ['BAC','C','GS','JPM','MS','WFC']
BAC = {tick:data.DataReader(tick, 'stooq', start, end) for tick in tickers}
```